# Excel vba show small title bar

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is to display an Excel window with title bar, scroll bars, and nothing else menu-wise.

I have been using a combination of the following:

```
With Application 
    .Executeexcel4macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
    .CommandBars(1).Enabled = False
    .CommandBars("ribbon").Enabled = False
    .DisplayFormulaBar = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
 End with
```

My problem is, this sometimes removes the title bar completely. I want the small title bar, with just *minimize*, *maximize* and *close* buttons. Not having a title bar at all is a problem.

As a side note, if anyone knows how to disable the *File* menu, advice is welcome.

Edit: problem solved. It was due to having multiple hidden windows, and executing above code multiple times. Apparently excel gets confused. Solved by executing code on workbook open, once.

Comment: Why not just `application.DisplayFullScreen = True`

Comment: Because the user must be able to use the other windows of my application. Or other windows entirely

Comment: Sounds like you want to display your spreadsheets in some "Excel viewer", not Microsoft Excel. What's the rationale for this?

Comment: Just tried with application.disaplayfull screen. Turns out it does not display full screen as I thought. It displays as I want but there is one problem: if the users uses the restore button (say they want to see the window side by side with another)  the title bar disseapears

Comment: @mat's mug my application is essentially a large userform. Most of the time data is displayed received thought said userform. However there is a particular set of data that must be shown in excel itself. There used to be a userform control to insert a sheet but it has been deprecated.

Comment: So, basically as I said: you made a VBA program that should really be a standalone desktop application, and now you're trying to "hide" the fact that it's hosted in Excel. I'd say that's pushing it a bit. If you want to write a desktop application, don't write it in VBA.

Comment: @mat's mug you sir, are one hundred percent correct. However here is a bit of context: I did not know anything about vba until about four months ago. The projected started as a spreassheet to help a friend. So I have most of it done, but they are asking me for an interface. I know this app should have been made in another language but for now porting it is out of the question, because that would mean learning another language from nothing, and for now I dont have the time.

Comment: And as for hiding excel... It's more about making it foolproof than security. My users will know this runs on excel. But I don't want to give them the ability to screw up. So if I manage to hide the menus completely, that would do.